# How to track form changes in react for analytics

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I am using react, redux and redux-saga. Now the thing is i want to track all the user interactions with the form such as onfocus timestamp, what he enters and when he submits. I want one common component that should do all the things like above for me. How to do this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you want to track all the action triggered as a result of user actions. Example when user submits the form. You want to log "MY_FORM_ACTION/FORM_SUBMIT" and "MY_FORM_ACTION/FORM_SUBMIT_SUCCESS" or "MY_FORM_ACTION/FORM_SUBMIT_FAILURE" as well. Use middleware.

You can type all your form actions something like "MY_FORM_ACTION/ACTION_NAME"

and write a simple middleware like below

```
const FormLogger = store => next => action => {
  if(action.type.includes('MY_FORM_ACTION/')){
  // log your action here 

}
   next(action)
}
```

Then in the If condition you can send them to a server or just log it. This middleware will capture all form actions which have "MY_FORM_ACTION/". Add this middleware to your redux just like saga or thunk middleware and it will work!

else You can have a TracMe Component like below.

```
Const TrackMe = Component => props =>{  

const {onChange, onClick, onBlur, ...rest} = props;

const logChange = (e) =>{
//log Change 
if(onChange){onChange(e)
}

const logClick = (e) =>{
//log Click 
if(onClick){onClick(e)
}

const logBlur = (e) =>{
//log blur 
if(onBlur){onBlur(e)
}

return (<Component 
         onChange={logChange}
         onClick={logClick}
         onBlur={logBlur}
         {...rest}/>)
    }
```

Now if your component is `<Input  {…props } />` just wrap it with `TrackMe(<Input  {…props } />`

Comment: Not a perfect use case at all, see my answer above. Also, he is asking for a common **component** to do this.

Comment: Well It is! If you read the redux documentation on middleware.  Read in the link https://redux.js.org/advanced/middleware.

Comment: https://redux.js.org/advanced/middleware. In fact it teaches middleware creation by creating logger middleware. Also wrapping all the forms in HOC is un-necessary when you can write one function in the middleware and all the form actions will be captured. So i would say it is a perfect use-case.

Comment: You can write it to capture one, multiple or all form actions and other developers on the team would not have to remember to wrap all form components they want to capture actions in HOC.example redux-logger is a very popular middleware to log actions.

Comment: No. The logger middleware is about logging redux actions, so this doesn't apply here. What you're describing is a different approach where all **actions** that are related to forms are identifyable as such, but that's not what this post is asking for. You would also be piping the timestamps through redux actions for no reason - they are not relevant for the application state at all, they only need to be passed along with the tracking requests.

Comment: "You can write it to capture one, multiple or all form actions" - HOC accomplishes the same, plus you're still able to *not* track if that need should occur.

"other developers on the team would not have to remember to wrap all form components" - That's a bogus argument, the other developers would know that the application is tracking form interaction. They'd have to know how your middleware works in your scenario instead.

Both approaches add complexity, yet yours is misusing middlewares for something redux is not meant for. How exactly is tracking part of the app's state?

Comment: I don't think so. Repeating again, Redux docs teach us creating middleware by creating a logger. So i don't think creating logger using middleware is misusing it! 
Also I would rather prefer to write my logic in middleware for any type of logger since all actions  are guaranteed to pass through it. hence, the argument of "other developers on the team do not have to remember to wrap all form components". Other devs most likely will not create random action types. For form actions there would already be a established convention.

Comment: So this argument is not at all bogus just put a check in middleware to log that type of actions.
Most important HOC  will fail if action originates from a saga/ thunk to suppose say clear a input on API call. If a need arises to log all actions changing the input field . HOCs can not log this.However Since all actions will definitely pass through middleware, this will also be logged if required.
Hence i believe middleware for this would be ideal as a long term solution.

Comment: You keep going on about the logger without answering the question what **tracking form interaction** has to do with application state (hint: nothing). Just because something works doesn't mean it's the best approach and architecturally pure. Your saga/ argument: In this case you call the tracking helper from the action creators. It's not a component's job to track something that doesn't happen in the component. You keep justifying your approach with hypothetical arguments about future code use by developers we don't know - while the post was asking for a component to track form interaction.

Comment: Just because a HOC was asked also doesn't mean that HOC is the best and the only way.  Logging for analytics i strongly feel is a middleware's job. These are not hypothetical arguments, you need to think of what can be easily scaled to meet ever changing requirements. That is why most of the loggers we use are middleware's not HOCs be it redux logger or crash reporters.

Comment: Why is analytics a **redux** middleware's job? There is no effect on the application state. The **user** interaction with the form needs tracking *not* the resulting **redux** actions. These are separate things. The  tracking requests are fired off and forgotten, and not reflected in the state at all. Tracking is a separate concern from managing the application state and you seem to be in denial about that. Your scaling/changing requirements argument is superfluous because the HOC perfectly scales the same way. You implement it once and use it everywhere a form needs tracking. Done.

Comment: You seem to be oblivious about the fact that most of the loggers used currently in the ecosystem are middleware not HOCs. Also as already explained above actions which change the form inputs but originate from sagas/thunks could never be logged via HOCs but middleware could easily log them.

Comment: Actions which originate from sagas or thunks **are not initiated by the user** and therefore don't require tracking. You keep using the word *logger* but we're not talking about logging here. I think this discussion is pointless, as you confuse logging and analytics tracking and keep overlooking the original requirement of this question (a component for tracking a user's form interaction).

Comment: I get your point. For this simple use case both could solve the problem. However, my view remains unchanged that if middleware is used it could even be extended to log all actions sync/async triggered by a user action if required in future, which a HOC could never achieve. Since middlewares are a tunnel for all the actions in the application, any change in logging requirement can be easily achieved, which would not be possible with HOCs.

Comment: Yeah in this hypothetical future scenario where for some reason all form interaction happens with redux actions, sagas trigger other form actions, and devs can't be bother to use `<TrackableInput>` instead of `<input>` your solution is really.. awesome.

Comment: I guess you are right! That’s why everyone in the entire ecosystem is creating logger middle-wares and not HOCs for these hypothetical requirements.

Comment: You seriously need to go back to the original question and read it again. Redux isn't even remotely involved in the actual goal for this. Form interaction happens between the user, the DOM and React. Nobody wants to log anything or write middlewares. You got thrown off because redux and saga is also mentioned. Sure I wouldn't write a HOC for *logging* redux actions, that's ridiculous and irrelevant.

Comment: Reading the question again. I think you have a fair point. Redux and saga had me believed that he would want to track all actions that are triggered resulting a user action. Well i have edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would disagree that this a perfect use case for a middleware. The tracking is a side-effect of user interaction and not really related to redux, as sending off analytics data does not affect the application state.

You probably want some kind of HOC `<TrackableInput>` which has event handlers for `onChange`, `onFocus`, etc. and each of these handlers **fires analytics requests**, as a side effect, before dispatching an action like `INPUT_CHANGE_VALUE`. Separate the concerns of tracking and managing application state.

```
const trackFormEvent = (type, value = null) => {
    console.log('Track form event of type', type, 'with value:', value);
    // Do actual tracking request in here.
};

class TrackableInput extends React.Component {
    onChange = (changeEvent) => {
        const { value } = changeEvent.target;
        trackFormEvent('change', value);
        this.props.onChange(value);
    };

    onFocus = (focusEvent) => {
        trackFormEvent('focus');
        this.props.onFocus(focusEvent);
    };

    onBlur = (blurEvent) => {
        trackFormEvent('blur');
        this.props.onBlur(blurEvent);
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <input
                {...this.props}
                onChange={this.onChange}
                onFocus={this.onFocus}
                onBlur={this.onBlur}
            />
        );
    }
}
```